# how to force linearlayout within a constraintlayout to fully occupy its scope

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

in the below layout, i am trying to practice constarint layout. as stated in the code below, i have a Framelayouts that should be divided horizontally. it is also has a purple background.

the point is, the purple background does not fully occupy the middle section. please let me know how to achieve that using the constarintlayout.

**code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topButtonsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/topBtn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="topBtn1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/topBtn_2"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/topBtn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="topBtn2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/topBtn_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/topBtn_3"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/topBtn_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="topBtn3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/topBtn_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LowerButtonsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomBtn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BottomBtn1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bottomBtn_2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomBtn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BottomBtn2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bottomBtn_1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bottomBtn_3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomBtn_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BottomBtn3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bottomBtn_2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick="clicksHandler"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you upload an image/drawing of your wanted layout?

Comment: *the 2 textviews on the left and the 2 textview on the right..* there is not a single TextView in the xml you posted!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was not so clear, you have said something about textViews but there are 0 of them in  your layout, here is my answer **based on what I understood from the question:**

---

If you want an easy solution just to maximize the scope of the fragmentContainer simply change its height to `0dp` and constraint the top of fragmentContainer to the bottom of the top part and constraint the bottom part of fragmentContainer to the top of your bottom part like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#f88813"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/LowerButtonsContainer"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topButtonsContainer">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

---

### For a better solution and better understanding  of ConstraintLayout:

In your layout, you have A-lot of nested views (ConstraintLayout->LinearLayout->FrameLayout).

Constraint layout is not meant for nested view groups, the purpose of ConstraintLayout is for you to have a flat view hierarchy.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout):

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

If you want to better design your wanted layout I would use [Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) for the top and bottom part of your screen, and probably for the middle part to divide it into 2 different areas.

**So something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Buttons"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="we are"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="top"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Buttons"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="we are"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Hey I am blue"
    android:background="#ff123456"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="And i am orange "
    android:background="#f88813"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

---

**Notice that in my more detailed example I have 0 nested view group thus my layout will work faster.**